# Babel string interpolation error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a bunch of input elements to which I want to assign unique ids.

However, the following string interpolation (`i` is the mapped element index)

```
id = `input-add-${i}`
```

returns

```
Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text
```

I use interpolation successfully elsewhere, so I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, my bad. I forgot the curly brackets.

This works

```
{ id={`input-add-${i}`} }
```

and this would also work

```
id={'input-add-' + i}
```